# I have addede a navigation drawer and admmob banner in my android application ,but it shows error "Cannot resolve R"

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, navigation-drawer

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mypc.hitarthapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'

}
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.mypc.hitarthapp;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.*;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DrawerLayout dl;
    NavigationView nv;
    AdView av;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-7900332792984616/4506141248");
        dl=findViewById(R.id.dv);
        nv=findViewById(R.id.nv);
        av=findViewById(R.id.ad);
        nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                item.setChecked(true);
                dl.closeDrawers();
                AdRequest ar=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                av.loadAd(ar);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/dv"
>
<android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/nv"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/myheader"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitID="ca-app-pub-7900332792984616/4506141248"
    >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I got this error-

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs 
for details
```

I have also tried Cleaning and rebuilding my project

Is there something wrong in my dependencies or Should I change my layout?
any help will be appreciated
thanks in advance

my logcat
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDgYg.png)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: try to run project so you can get actual error in console

Comment: this is what i got:AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709023/errorjava-util-concurrent-executionexception-com-android-builder-internal-aapt/50057711 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769455/error-java-util-concurrent-executionexception-com-android-builder-internal-aap/50802826

Comment: post log details

Comment: what gradle version are you using?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

Comment: This isn't gradle version. It's android plugin version.

Comment: Check the logs for details. Go to the Terminal window and run "gradlew assembleDebug" and post the output here (both standard output and standard error).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27. Remove `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'`. You've added two appcompat libs. Then sync, clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: the same error   :Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs 
for details